# Crawling option tag with Php

Tags: php, web-crawler

I tried many things but i could not read the value on  tag. 
I look similar examples here and on the different blogs but solution given there didnt solve my problem.

Html is like this on the site :

```
<div>
   <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCityID" id="ddlCityID">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="14">Roma</option>
        <option value="15">Milan</option>
        <option value="16">Inter</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

My code on php :

```
$pageTitle = 'select[@id="ddlCityID"]';
$html = file_get_html($url);

  if ($html != null )
  {
     foreach($html->find($pageTitle) as $element) 
     {
    $link = $element->find('option');
    callfunction($link[0]->option);
     }
  }
```

Error :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Aptana Studio 3 = a.php on line 57
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Aptana Studio 3 = a.php on line 57
```

Where is my problem and how can i get value of  tag, and the text in the tag.

Thanks;

Comment: var_dump `$link` to see if it's an array. probably you have to access it in a different way

Comment: $link = $element->find('option'); is line 57

Comment: Not sure what you are actually doing here. So your full HTML page is in a file and you want to parse that file with XPath functions? You should NOT parse any website with xml functions. Htmlpages are only very rarely xml compatible and will most probably crash your script. I would try a more basic approach with str_pos and substr functions.

Comment: Or ... did you just use JQuery functions on your PHP code?

Comment: How can i parse this piece of code with str_pos?

Answer (score 0):

Continue using simplehtmldom instead of str_pos (I would however suggest to change parser, since simplehtmldom is quite heavy).

The solution you're seeking is this

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$str = '<div>
   <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCityID" id="ddlCityID">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="14">Roma</option>
        <option value="15">Milan</option>
        <option value="16">Inter</option>
   </select>
</div>';

$pageTitle = 'select[id=ddlCityID]';
$html = str_get_html($str);

if ($html != null ) {
    foreach($html->find($pageTitle) as $element) {
        foreach($element->find('option') as $trueElement) {
            echo $trueElement->innertext;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that innertext will give you 'Choose', 'Roma', 'Milan', 'Inter'.
trueElement now holds every OPTION tag.

Also the '@' before 'id', is useless.

UPDATE: This is the full **working** code I tested.

Comment: i tried you solution, it is not entering in second for, is not finding option tag on $element. What can be the problem?

Comment: Paste me some text, I can't deduce what's happening (also I tested it before posting, and it works fine).

Comment: foreach($html->find($pageTitle) as $element) {
     echo "step1";
      foreach($element->find('option') as $trueElement) {
        echo "step2";
          echo $trueElement->innertext;
      }
   }
Solution is just step1

Comment: There is no error, just not entering in second loop,
echo $element is ->
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCityID" id="ddlCityID">     </select>

Comment: That's odd, are you sure the html you gave us is exactly the same. Since inside <select>HERE</select> there should be the three options.

Comment: Unfortunately the options are populated using javascript, and as far as I know there's no way to get the page with javascript being executed.

Comment: Can you recomend me something how to crawl it ?

Comment: I can't think of anything that will do the job automatically, I however suggest you to debug the javascript code (if you use firefox, firebug is a good debugger) to find the responsible of the insertion. That way, it shouldn't be too difficult to retrieve from the source of the insertion function.